# EFCore/UWP missing some tables with Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm starting to use EFCore in a UWP app with SQLite. I've declared the classes that I want stored in the database. I've then declared various DbSets and the OnConfiguring override:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SourceDescription> SourceDescriptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PlaceDescription> PlaceDescriptions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=Testing.db");
    }
}
```

In the Package Manager Console, I then go:

```
Add-Migration 2017-06-23
```

and it creates the code to then build the database. HOWEVER, that code is missing some of the top-level tables. Some of them are there but some aren't and I can't see/figure out what is causing this. No errors are generated and I cannot find a pattern to determine why the missing tables are missing.

Further information:

- There are 29 classes defined in my code. The migration code creates 24 tables.
- Of the 5 "missing" classes, 4 of them are derived from Subject which, in turn, derives from Conclusion. The fifth is the Conclusion class. Since the migration code "merges" the properties from each of the derived classes, I'm not surprised that the Conclusion class doesn't have its own table as there is no direct use of it as a class.
- With the exception of the Conclusion class, the other 4 classes are only referenced in the DbSet properties (as opposed to be used in properties in other classes). As noted above, the Document class is derived from another class, so it isn't derived classes that is the common factor.
- It isn't that some of the classes are partial classes.
- I can't spot anything about the properties in the classes that is a common factor. For example, the Person class has List a couple of times but so does the Agent class and that *does* appear in the migration code.

Any suggestions on what I can look for or if this is a known issue?

Comment: Do some of the classes inherit other?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes but that isn't the answer, I'm afraid. I've added some more information to show that some of the derived classes do appear in the migration code.

Comment: The point is, if some base class is exposed via `DbSet`, or is referenced from navigation property of some entity, or is used as generic argument of `modelBuilder.Entity` call (as opposed to simple implementation inheritance), EF will consider it to be an entity and will use TPH strategy (i.e. create single table with discriminator). For instance, the 4 missing classes might have been consolidated in a `Subject` table. Check the migration for table with Discriminator column.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are correct - it does look like the missing classes have been consolidated into the definition of the Subject table. There is a Discriminator column on that table.

Comment: @IvanStoev ah ... so I don't actually need to worry that the tables are "missing". EF Core will sort it out automatically because the Discriminator column marks the derived type ... ? That is what http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy seems to be suggesting.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the answer provided by Ivan is that EF Core sees the four classes that are derived from the Subject class and builds a table for the Subject class that includes all of the properties for those derived classes. There is then a Discriminator column added to the Subject class that indicates which derived class this is for.

http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy is a good article for explaining it.

An interesting approach to designing database tables that I hadn't come across before. I live and learn :)